# How to pass dynamic values to a Query using SQLITE in Android ?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, split

i am trying to pass dynamic id to query every time no of passed id will change sometimes it may be 3 or  2 or etc.My question is how can i pass this id and select values from query.

```
String[] splits = clickedTopicIdString.split("-");
    Log.i("splits",""+splits.length); // length 2 bcoz clickedTopicIdString = 0-1 it may be 0-1-2 etc
    if(splits.length > 0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<splits.length;i++)
        {clickedTopicIdInt = Integer.parseInt(splits[i]);// i want to save values in an array and pass it GetQuestionData(); this method after converting it in integer.....
         Log.i("clickedTopicIdInt",""+clickedTopicIdInt);
        }

    }

    clickedTopicIdInt = Integer.parseInt(clickedTopicIdString);
    dbhelper = new JamiaBinoriaDBHelper(context);
    dbhelper.open();
    GetQuestionData();
```

This function will recieve id dynamically in form of arrays and will apply it here topic_question.topic_id="+topic_id1+" OR topic_question.topic_id="+topic_id2+"  and so on how can i do this?

```
public List<String> GetClickedIdImages(int topic_id)
    { List<String> questionImageNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String query = "SELECT topic_question.question_image_name FROM topic_question,topic WHERE topic_question.topic_id="+topic_id+" AND topic.id=topic_question.topic_id";   
   // Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT topic_question.question_image_name FROM topic_question,topic WHERE topic_question.topic_id=1 AND topic.id=topic_question.topic_id",null);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    Log.i("Cursor Query Print:",""+query);
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
         Log.d("cursor",""+cursor);
                questionImageNameList.add(cursor.getString(0));
                Log.i("cursor.getString(2)",""+cursor.getString(0));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("", "Cursor is Null");
            Log.d("retrieving all parameters", "count < 0");
        }

        cursor.close();
        return questionImageNameList;
    }
```

can someone please help me in this task ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your select dynamically basing on a list of IDs you shoud this SQL syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)
```

id1,id2 = your ids

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_where_clause.htm

```
String numbers = "1-2-3-4-5";
        String [] splits = numbers.split("-");
        Integer [] realNumbers = new Integer [splits.length];
        String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ";
        String whereStatement = "(";
        for (int i = 0; i<splits.length; i++)
        {
            realNumbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(splits[i]);
            whereStatement += realNumbers[i]+((i == splits.length -1) ? "" :",");

        }
        whereStatement += ");";

        sqlSelect += whereStatement; //your select SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: i want to use WHERE topicquestion.topicid = 0 OR topicquestion.topicid =1  etc can i use IN  instead of OR

Comment: You can test it here and check out if this solution is for you http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_in

Comment: i am using sqlite not sql

Comment: In SQLite is also WHERE IN : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_where_clause.htm

Comment: if(splits.length > 0)
        {
         for(int i=0;i<splits.length;i++)
         {clickedTopicIdInt = Integer.parseInt(splits[i]);
          Log.i("clickedTopicIdInt",""+clickedTopicIdInt);
          //idArrayInt[i] = clickedTopicIdInt;
         }
         //Log.i("idArrayInt",""+idArrayInt);
        }         here i am failed to convert string into arrayInt can u please help me how can i convert in intArray and pass it to query